# What characters are encoded by HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode?

Tags: c#

What characters are encoded by `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` and HttpUtility.UrlEncode`? The documentation does not seem to mention the exact characters encoded.

Answer (score 1):

The following unit test provides part of the the answer. However what I was really looking for was UrlEncode() - see last test. Hope this helps someone

```
public class HtmlDecodeTest
{
    ////https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/
    //char[] chars = { ';', '/', '?', ':', '@', '=', '&', '<', '>', '#', '%', '{', '}', '|', '\\', '^', '~', '[', ']', '`', ' ' };

    [Fact]
    public void NotEncodedTest()
    {
        var msg = ";,/,?,:,@,=,#,%,{,},|.\\,^,~,[,],` ";
        var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(msg);
        Assert.Equal(msg, encoded);
        var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);
        Assert.Equal(msg, decoded);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void EncodedTest()
    {
        var msg = "<,>,&";
        var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(msg);
        Assert.Equal("&lt;,&gt;,&amp;", encoded);
        var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);
        Assert.Equal(msg, decoded);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void UrlEncodedTest()
    {
        var msg = "<>&/?:@=#%{}|\\^~[]` end";
        var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(msg);

        char[] invalidChars = { ';', '/', '?', ':', '@', '=', '&', '<', '>', '#', '{',
                         '}', '|', '\\', '^', '~', '[', ']', '`', ' ' };
        Assert.True(encoded.IndexOfAny(invalidChars) == -1);

        Assert.Equal("%3c%3e%26%2f%3f%3a%40%3d%23%25%7b%7d%7c%5c%5e%7e%5b%5d%60+end", encoded);
        var decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encoded);
        Assert.Equal(msg, decoded);
    }
}
```

Comment: It encodes more than that. For example, it encodes "".

Comment: _"The following unit test provides the answer"_ - that test does not cover all characters.

Comment: It would be great to get a definitive list of all the characters that these methods encode. That's what should be in the Microsoft docs.